# How do I determine $\min \left \| \vec{v}-\vec{u} \right \|_2$ for $\vec{u}\in U$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $U=\lambda ((1, 0, 1, 0)^T,(1, 1, 0, 1)^T,(1, -1, 1; 0)^T$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$. Determine for $\vec{v} = (1, 1, 1, 1)^T$ the vector $\vec{u}\in U$ minimal with $\left \| \vec{v}-\vec{u} \right \|_2$. Determine further $\left \| \vec{v}-\vec{u} \right \|_2$ for $\vec{u}\in U$?

Comment: Do you know how to determine an orthogonal projection on a subspace?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\vec x=\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\end{pmatrix}\in U^\perp$,
observe that
\begin{align}
&\vec x\cdot\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}=0&
&\Longrightarrow& &x_1+x_3=0,\tag{1}\\[5pt]
&\vec x\cdot\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}=0&
&\Longrightarrow& &x_1+x_2+x_4=0,\tag{2}\\[5pt]
&\vec x\cdot\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}=0&
&\Longrightarrow& &x_1-x_2+x_3=0.\tag{3}
\end{align}
By solving equations $(1)$, $(2)$, and $(3)$, we obtain $x_2=0$ and 
$x_3=x_4=-x_1$, and thus $U^\perp={\rm span}{\left(\left\{(1,0,-1,-1)^T\right\}\right)}$. Now, we may assume
\begin{align}
\vec v
=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}1-a\\1\\1+a\\1+a\end{pmatrix}
+\begin{pmatrix}a\\0\\-a\\-a\end{pmatrix}=\vec v_1+\vec v_2,
\end{align}
such that $\vec v_1=\begin{pmatrix}1-a\\1\\1+a\\1+a\end{pmatrix}\in U$ and
$\vec v_2=\begin{pmatrix}a\\0\\-a\\-a\end{pmatrix}\in U^\perp$.
Solve the following equation
\begin{align}
&\vec v_1\cdot\vec v_2=0&&\Longrightarrow&&
a(1-a)-2a(1+a)=0\\
&&&\Longrightarrow&& a(3a+1)=0\\
&&&\Longrightarrow&& a=0\quad\mbox{or}\quad a=-\frac{1}{3}.
\end{align}
If $a=0$, then $\vec v_1=\vec v$ and then 
$\vec v_1\cdot\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\-1\\-1\end{pmatrix}
=\vec v\cdot\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\-1\\-1\end{pmatrix}=-1\ne 0$,
which contradicts to the assumption that $\vec v_1\in U=U^{\perp\perp}$.
Eventually we conclude that
$$\vec v_1=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{4}{3}\\1\\\frac{2}{3}\\\frac{2}{3}\end{pmatrix}
\quad\mbox{and}\quad \vec v_2=\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{1}{3}\\0\\\frac{1}{3}\\\frac{1}{3}\end{pmatrix}$$
and therefore given $\vec u\in U$,
\begin{align}
\left\Vert \vec v-\vec u\right\Vert_2^2
=\left\Vert (\vec v_1-\vec u)+\vec v_2\right\Vert_2^2
=\left\Vert \vec v_1-\vec u\right\Vert_2^2+\left\Vert\vec v_2\right\Vert_2^2
\geq \left\Vert\vec v_2\right\Vert_2^2=\frac{1}{3}.
\end{align}
That is, $\left\Vert \vec v-\vec u\right\Vert_2\ge\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ and
its minimum is attained at $\vec u=\vec v_1$.